# iterating over the return value of a method in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class Foo like so:

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<Bar> barVec() const {return barVec_;}

private:
    std::vector<Bar> barVec_;
};
```

where Bar is some other class. So outside of Foo the only access to barVec_ is via the method barVec().

If myFoo is an instance of Foo, and pred is a unary predicate on Bar, is it okay to do something like this:

```
auto i = find_if(myFoo.barVec().begin(), myFoo.barVec().end(), pred);
if (i != myFoo.barVec().end()) {
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Or do I have to assign myFoo.barVec() to a variable and iterate over that variable? For example:

```
std::vector<Bar> tmp = myFoo.barVec();
auto i = find_if(tmp.begin(), tmp.end, pred);
if (i != tmp.end()) {
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is it okay..."? If you are asking if it will compile, you should try it. If you are asking something else, you should be more explicit with your question.

Comment: @Code-Guru I actually think that asking “is it ok” is unambiguous in this case.

Comment: What does the "c" in your question's title mean?

Comment: Sorry, first post on stackoverflow. I've edited it now, Hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo::barVec()` returns a copy of a vector each time you call it. So the iterators returned by two calls to `Foo::barVec().begin()` and `Foo::barVec().end()` belong to different objects.

You probably meant to return a reference:

```
const std::vector<Bar>& barVec() const {return barVec_;}
```

but you should consider returning providing methods that return the `begin()` and `end()` iterators from your class directly, instead of exposing the underlying vector data member.

Answer (score 6):

No, it’s not OK since you make a **copy** of the vector when returning it so the iterators that you’re comparing refer to different containers, which is undefined behaviour.

You could just return a (`const`-) reference but it’s much cleaner to overload `begin` and `end` for your class proper rather than exposing the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `myBar` should be `myFoo` and be of type `Foo`.

You have to assign it to a `std::vector<Bar>` object first. The problem is that `myFoo.barVec()` returns a copy of the vector stored inside `myFoo`. Each of the calls to `barVec` in your `find_if` line will return a different temporary `std::vector<Bar>` object. The `begin` and `end` iterators for those two temporary objects do not apply to the same sequence. This means you have undefined behaviour.